# Populate tableview with multiple Alamofire chained requests

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, alamofire, completionhandler

I am new at Alamofire and I am following the book IOS Apps with REST APIs, where I try to parse JSON and populate the tableview but the problem is that it calls numberOfRowsInSection before the function loadGists finishes calling the Alamofire chained requests so I can populate the Array and then populate the tableview accordingly, it seems that .responseArray function is called Asynchronous or called after numberOfRowsInSection function.

```
var gists: [Gist]!

@IBOutlet var tabelView1: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



self.tabelView1.delegate = self
        self.tabelView1.dataSource = self
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    loadGists()
    }


func loadGists() {
GitHubAPIManager.sharedInstance.getPublicGists() { result in
guard result.error == nil else {
print(result.error)
// TODO: display error
return
}
if let fetchedGists = result.value {
self.gists = fetchedGists
}
DispatchQueue.main.async  {
    self.tableView1.reloadData()
    }

}
    }
```

Where GitHubAPIManager Class has:

```
class GitHubAPIManager: NSObject {


static let sharedInstance = GitHubAPIManager()

func getPublicGists(completionHandler: (Result<[Gist]>) -> Void) {
Alamofire.request(GistRouter.GetPublic())
.responseArray { (response) in
completionHandler(response.result)
}
}
}
```

And responseArray is:

```
public func responseArray<T: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable>(
completionHandler: Response<[T]) -> Self {
let serializer = ResponseSerializer<[T]> { request, response, data, error in
guard error == nil else {
return .Failure(error!)
}
guard let responseData = data else {
let failureReason = "Array could not be serialized because input data was nil."
let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed,
failureReason: failureReason)
return .Failure(error)
}
let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response,
responseData, error)
switch result {
case .Success(let value):
let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(value)
var objects: [T] = []
for (_, item) in json {
if let object = T(json: item) {
objects.append(object)
}
}
return .Success(objects)
case .Failure(let error):
return .Failure(error)
}
}
return response(responseSerializer: serializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

For table view:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return gists.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath
indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
let gist = gists[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel!.text = gist.description
cell.detailTextLabel!.text = gist.ownerLogin

return cell
}
```

GistRouter is:

```
enum GistRouter: URLRequestConvertible {

    static let baseURLString:String = "https://api.github.com"

    case getPublic() 




        var method: HTTPMethod {

            switch self {

            case .getPublic:
                return .get
            }
        }

        func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {

        let result: (path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?) = {

            switch self {
            case .getPublic:
                return ("/gists/public", nil)
            }
        }()


        let URL = Foundation.URL(string: GistRouter.baseURLString)!




            var UrlRequest: URLRequest? = URLRequest(url: URL.appendingPathComponent(result.path))

            UrlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(UrlRequest!, with: result.parameters)


        UrlRequest?.httpMethod = method.rawValue

        return UrlRequest!
    }
```

And Gist Class is:

```
class Gist: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable  {


    var id: String?
    var description: String?
    var ownerLogin: String?
    var ownerAvatarURL: String?
    var url: String?


    required init(json: SwiftyJSON.JSON) {
        self.description = json["description"].string
        self.id = json["id"].string
        self.ownerLogin = json["owner"]["login"].string
        self.ownerAvatarURL = json["owner"]["avatar_url"].string
        self.url = json["url"].string
    }
    required init() {
    }

}
```

I have tried DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async  and also
                let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0) in different ways with no luck, I need to have Alamofire chained requests all done first and then numberOfRowsInSection  called, please help.

Comment: Please add your methods for `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: You have defined tableView1 but are asking tableView.reloadData().  And I can't see if you are actually running your completion handler just passing it around.  So the reloadData isn't running, instead it's just the normal Table View behaviour running whilst Alamo Fire is doing its stuff.

Comment: I added the tableview methods and corrected with  self.tableView1.reloadData(), but same thing and whatever is inside the block of GitHubAPIManager.sharedInstance.getPublicGists(){result in ...} is not executed before numberOfRowsInSection is called, it is called after instead

Comment: public func responseArray<T: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable>(
completionHandler: Response<[T]) -> Self {       Have you miscoded this....Response<[T]>) -> Self {.  I can see the completion handler is being called now (the formatting doesn't help!!)

Comment: I meant: I still can't see the completion handler being called but the formatting doesn't help

Comment: Ok, now I see where it is being called.  However, you may also have miscoded this:  func getPublicGists(completionHandler: (Result<[Gist])  ... func getPublicGists(completionHandler: (Result<[Gist]>)

Comment: ad-johnson getPublicGists is already there, you can see it, I added Gist and GistRouter

Comment: No, I meant it looks like you have miscoded the function definitions.  Look what I wrote.  Does Xcode not flag these syntax errors for you?  In both cases it looks like you are missing a closing >

Comment: My mistake in the code above, but still have the same issue

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on that reload statement to see if/when it is reached?

Comment: ad-johnson, thank you bro I followed the execution using breakpoint but no luck, and then I added the didset callback and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with:

```
var gists = [Gist]() {
        didSet {

            self.tabelView1.reloadData()

        }
    }
```